# Check if a value is present in a particular column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tony','Mathew'],'Value':['1','2']})
```

How do I check if  'Tony' exists in column 'Name'? I tried the following, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
print(bool('Tony' in df.Name))
```

Which is always returning False despite 'Tony' being present in column 'Name'

Comment: @yatu the question you marked is not a duplicate. The question you tagged has a list, which compares itself with a particular column in dataframe and again return a Series with values True/False. What I want is to find if a string is present or not in a particular column

Comment: `df.Name.isin(['Tony'])`. Or in your case if you want to use `in`, `'Tony' in df.Name.values.tolist()`. Doesnt work with pdSeries directly

Comment: @yatu, ''Tony' in df.Name.values.tolist()' This is what I wanted, thanks :)